# how do I add items to a list that match?

Tags: java

As I process each country, how do I add only the languages with matching country id for that country?

```
  private List<String> readCountryLanguages(Statement sqlStatement, List<Country>countries) throws SQLException {
    List<String> languages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Country country : countries )  {
    ResultSet resultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery("SELECT language FROM COUNTRY_LANGUAGE");
     while (resultSet.next()) {
        String language = new String(resultSet.getString("Languages"));

        Country obj = new Country(0, language, 0, 0);
         obj.getId();
        }
    }
    return languages;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about your table structure of COUNTRY_LANGUAGE but you can update the sql query to something like.

```
SELECT language FROM COUNTRY_LANGUAGE WHERE country='" + country.getName()  + "'
```

Here I am assuming you have a column "country" in your COUNTRY_LANGUAGE table and country name can be retrieve from Country object by calling `Country.getName()`. But you can use the exact method from your actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

1. return the Country id in a variable when you iterate; you should have something like `country.getId()`;
2. `ResultSet resultSet = sqlStatement.executeQuery("SELECT language FROM COUNTRY_LANGUAGE where id='countryIdVariable'");`
3. change your sql query to be parametized/prepared statement so you can prevent sql injection and also add variable easier instead of having to write variable within single quote in your sql string.

Answer (score 0):

AS menthion by Asura, First of all change your sql query that returns language where contryId is 'something'

then in while loop add each **language** to **languages** list object by using add() method like this :

```
while (resultSet.next()) {
    String language = resultSet.getString("Languages");
    // add to list 
    languages.add(language);
    }
}
```